# Silverlight Toolkit TreeView Drag and Drop

Tags: silverlight, treeview, drag-and-drop

Does any know how to implement drag and drop in the silverlight toolkit's treeview?

I saw the drag and drop manager for silverlight but supposedly you can put containers around the items you want to drag and drop but I wonder how I would do this on another treeviewitem exactly?

Maybe there is a better way or custom way? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Silverlight Toolkit October (09) release (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) has added support for drag and drop.

There is a great walk though of the new feature here: http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/08/new-with-silverlight-toolkit-drag-and.html

Answer (score 1):

One method that should work is using [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) controls.

First download the telerik controls then add a reference to `Telerik.Windows.Controls`; that will allow you to use the `IsDragnDropEnable` property for the source treeview and the `.AllowDrop` for the Targeted TreeView

Comment: Note: commercial $$ add-on library